# Where should I ask a forum type question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Now and then I have a forum type questions about PHP and it's features that I would like to discuss about.

Is there a place in the Stack Exchange network, where I can ask those type of questions?

Comment: Try a chatroom.

Comment: Depends on what **exactly** your question is?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/ (some excellent discussions there every now and then)

Comment: Example, if I want to discuss, what is a better way: `To use @ or isset` ?

Comment: I think http://slant.co is pretty well designed to handle the more 'discussiony' questions that Stack Exchange is not. It was created to handle that niche (I'm not affiliated with them in any way).

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

You should ask a forum-type question on a forum, which Stack Exchange is not.

You can have discussions in chat as [Daniel Fischer suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170224/where-should-i-ask-a-forum-type-question#comment503401_170224). But that's not the same as a forum. If you want to have a discussion on a forum, *have a discussion on a forum.*

Stack Exchange is not designed to be, and cannot be, everything. Not all valuable content on the Internet can or should be on Stack Exchange.

Some subjective questions and answers, which share some features with *discussions*, can take place on some Stack Exchange sites, most notably [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (see [their FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) and [these guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)). But it sounds like you want a forum; I recommend finding one.

Some such discussions *might* be appropriate for some [official php mailing lists](http://news.php.net/).

Comment: I totally understand that, that's why I am asking, **where to**? There are lot's of professionals here, but I don't know any other place ( or forum ), where there are such a professional community.

Comment: @DainisAbols: incidentally, that's not a coincidence. Forums, and especially the subjective questions you're asking about, have a tendency to drive away qualified professionals.

Comment: That is in fact true